# Python check for null cursor using for

Tags: python, null, cursor, flags

I have a python script that I want to perform an action for each row found in a table or report if no rows were found.

This is some dummy code for troubleshooting

```
cur_users = lv_pgsql.cursor()

cur_users.execute("select * from users where us_idno > 10")

for lr_users in cur_users:
   print("ping")
```

I know I will be able to check if I attempt to store the results in an array like bellow

```
la_users = cur_users.fetchall()

if len(la_users) != 0:
   print("ping")
```

But is it possible to check with the above code as well without using fetchall?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code in a try except block, thus if the cursor is None it will throw an error. Also by doing this you can capture other errors and handle them.

Answer (score -1):

```
if cur_users.execute("select * from users where us_idno > 10").rowcount:
    print "ping!"
```

should do what you want?